# Adding new data to power BI source

Tags: mysql, database, powerbi, connection

Is there any options to add new values in source in Power BI. I have query that checked some status in my system everyday and I want power bi not to overwrite my values from yesterday just add new one.
For example
12.12.2021 - OK (checked 12.12.2021)
13.12.2021 - OK (checked 13.12.2021)
14.12.2021 - NOT OK (checked 14.12.2021)

Comment: You can simply insert into the database. That way it will add new rows.